# Adding a geom_point at the maximum of a stacked geom_col plot - coloured by a variable outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 11
       V1     V2      V3     V4      V5      V6      V7      V8   GRP    ID OUTCOME
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1  0.667  0.539  0.373  -0.774  0.197  -0.0816 -0.0835  0.189      1   166       1
 2 -0.436 -0.592 -0.686  -0.364 -0.0200 -0.0360  0.0285 -0.147      1    61       1
 3 -0.631 -0.573 -0.705  -0.287 -0.0507  0.0474  0.0182 -0.0702     1    54       1
 4  0.418  0.731  0.500   0.262 -0.0979  0.0353  0.0450  0.0156     1   240       0
 5  1.03   0.281 -0.0649 -0.670  0.223   0.138   0.0336  0.162      1   179       1
 6 -0.200  0.312  0.492   0.398 -0.0372 -0.0175  0.0101  0.0322     1   272       0
 7 -0.595 -0.549 -0.606  -0.308 -0.0358 -0.0281 -0.0478 -0.0832     1    76       0
 8 -0.289 -0.854 -1.01    0.169 -0.0207 -0.0149 -0.0742 -0.162      1    87       1
 9  0.608  0.392  0.478   0.223 -0.0372 -0.0495  0.0101  0.0479     1   224       1
10  0.707  0.595  0.496   0.615 -0.0372 -0.0209 -0.149   0.0682     1   164       1
```

I can plot the data using:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(OUTCOME) %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(V1:V8)) %>% 
  setNames(c("GRP", "ID", "OUTCOME", "name", "value")) %>% # not sure why but the column name for OUTCOME was changing too - OUTCOME[,"outcome"] so I had to add a "setNames()" 
  ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(width = 1, alpha = 0.9)
```

Where I want to arrange by `OUTCOME` and then plot such that the `OUTCOME` = `0` comes first and the `OUTCOME` = `1` comes second in the plot.

i.e. the x-axis corresponds to `ID`'s and therefore I want the first 1:26 observations (which are `0` - `OUTCOME`) observations at the begining and the 27:50 ( which are `1` - `OUTCOME`) observation at the end of the plot.

In order to make this more clear in the plot I want to add a `geom_vline(xintercept = 26)` to the plot (which currently does not seem to do anything). Secondly, I want to add a `geom_point` at the tip of each of the `geom_cols` which are coloured according to the `OUTCOME` variable - so each stacked `geom_col` will have a point at the top.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.666589915752411, -0.436222612857819, 
-0.631442725658417, 0.418105125427246, 1.03165137767792, -0.19955663383007, 
-0.595063030719757, -0.289468944072723, 0.608067691326141, 0.707050204277039, 
-0.352968633174896, -0.348733305931091, -0.734579741954803, -0.407550632953644, 
0.382651209831238, 0.317887604236603, 0.682134985923767, -1.3781418800354, 
-0.399168610572815, -0.718308925628662, 0.867228746414185, 0.679950773715973, 
0.839851379394531, -0.76373964548111, -1.42656266689301, -0.609997689723969, 
-0.385522603988647, 0.439238548278809, -0.456471681594849, -0.280009210109711, 
0.469753742218018, 0.318808495998383, -0.541835129261017, 0.842987537384033, 
0.452548682689667, 0.535462975502014, -0.364355206489563, -1.42656266689301, 
0.630698442459106, -0.44173675775528, -0.643441200256348, 0.685096621513367, 
1.14054381847382, 0.370130002498627, -0.619462072849274, -0.845775902271271, 
0.548840582370758, -0.477323114871979, -0.324755012989044, -0.781804263591766
), V2 = c(0.539071500301361, -0.59157657623291, -0.572662830352783, 
0.730981111526489, 0.281135410070419, 0.311570674180984, -0.549109578132629, 
-0.853675782680511, 0.392016798257828, 0.595141530036926, -0.566748976707458, 
0.478970289230347, -0.689719200134277, -0.291370570659637, 0.328506886959076, 
-1.00046491622925, 0.607915163040161, 0.167531609535217, -0.268897891044617, 
-0.669840693473816, 0.352877289056778, 0.335686177015305, 0.4686459004879, 
-0.120377041399479, 0.178255885839462, 0.242509573698044, 0.127220243215561, 
0.723466992378235, 0.169776439666748, 0.311570674180984, 0.241861879825592, 
-0.565791606903076, -0.596093893051147, 0.352877289056778, 0.755794286727905, 
0.237963885068893, -0.610303223133087, 0.178255885839462, 0.604371428489685, 
-0.566528797149658, -0.665839433670044, 0.572437882423401, -0.361080080270767, 
0.698914647102356, -0.539785265922546, 0.217821598052979, 0.808691143989563, 
0.50318056344986, -0.623627364635468, -0.344621360301971), V3 = c(0.373223125934601, 
-0.686219215393066, -0.705432772636414, 0.500304698944092, -0.0648666396737099, 
0.491708755493164, -0.60560667514801, -1.00564706325531, 0.477529734373093, 
0.496099144220352, -0.680513858795166, -0.289659559726715, -0.865037560462952, 
-0.3294717669487, 0.313058227300644, -0.659056186676025, 0.355539441108704, 
0.356298297643661, -0.742002785205841, -0.782470107078552, 0.462770104408264, 
0.524555385112762, 0.507511615753174, -0.400415688753128, 0.38832151889801, 
0.54375559091568, 0.348951697349548, 0.423646926879883, -0.22981920838356, 
0.472731471061707, 0.31219682097435, -0.381594121456146, -0.723009943962097, 
0.391745924949646, 0.414667755365372, 0.31219682097435, -0.779489040374756, 
0.38832151889801, 0.480808824300766, -0.666897296905518, -0.755469918251038, 
0.401484251022339, -0.543907880783081, 0.344876348972321, -0.528214573860168, 
-0.269392281770706, 0.56480598449707, 0.621908187866211, -0.531825602054596, 
-0.434289932250977), V4 = c(-0.773811459541321, -0.363897234201431, 
-0.287408024072647, 0.261809468269348, -0.670326471328735, 0.397776305675507, 
-0.307681560516357, 0.168681144714355, 0.223264053463936, 0.614758968353271, 
-0.338626772165298, -0.846252083778381, 0.11482846736908, -0.345179617404938, 
-1.05273842811584, -0.350423514842987, 0.196808382868767, 0.00778263807296753, 
0.189556911587715, 0.123728767037392, 0.583511531352997, 0.52887761592865, 
0.522512197494507, -0.343501180410385, 0.257596492767334, 0.581979811191559, 
-0.991406679153442, -0.863794207572937, -0.758265018463135, 0.374924182891846, 
-1.05103802680969, -0.504420638084412, 0.00401294603943825, 0.335065960884094, 
-0.823703289031982, -1.05103802680969, -0.353600144386292, 0.257596492767334, 
0.229928761720657, -0.338579297065735, -0.257122099399567, -0.802706837654114, 
0.196976840496063, -0.947062849998474, -0.328546792268753, -0.37180632352829, 
0.473592817783356, 0.396025836467743, -0.382713079452515, -0.403718531131744
), V5 = c(0.197130978107452, -0.0200146716088057, -0.0507026240229607, 
-0.0978699624538422, 0.222558438777924, -0.0371929332613945, 
-0.0357776693999767, -0.0207225400954485, -0.0371929332613945, 
-0.0371929332613945, -0.0357776693999767, -0.102090179920197, 
0.032932948321104, -0.0899124220013618, -0.102090179920197, 0.0611645467579365, 
0.0739013180136681, -0.0371929332613945, -0.0207225400954485, 
0.0266784615814686, -0.0371929332613945, -0.0371929332613945, 
-0.0978699624538422, -0.0507026240229607, -0.0371929332613945, 
-0.0371929332613945, -0.102090179920197, 0.222558438777924, -0.102090179920197, 
-0.0371929332613945, -0.102090179920197, -0.0442905239760876, 
-0.0356474928557873, -0.0371929332613945, 0.197130978107452, 
-0.102090179920197, -0.0507026240229607, -0.0371929332613945, 
0.0739013180136681, -0.0357776693999767, 0.0674190372228622, 
0.222558438777924, -0.0356474928557873, 0.197130978107452, -0.0357776693999767, 
0.193563550710678, 0.0484738424420357, 0.0484738424420357, -0.0357776693999767, 
0.0674190372228622), V6 = c(-0.0815747752785683, -0.0359503589570522, 
0.0473587699234486, 0.0353398211300373, 0.137635827064514, -0.017513670027256, 
-0.0280688628554344, -0.0148527026176453, -0.0495327338576317, 
-0.0209453999996185, -0.0280688628554344, -0.0714860409498215, 
0.0438234098255634, 0.120613776147366, -0.0714860409498215, -0.0342447310686111, 
0.0836121588945389, -0.0538526326417923, -0.0134977530688047, 
-0.0259735006839037, -0.017513670027256, -0.017513670027256, 
0.0353398211300373, 0.0394904688000679, -0.0380047224462032, 
-0.0380047224462032, -0.0495327338576317, 0.174676224589348, 
-0.0758059397339821, -0.0380047224462032, -0.0495327338576317, 
-0.0714860409498215, 0.0473587699234486, -0.017513670027256, 
-0.103528082370758, -0.0495327338576317, 0.0473587699234486, 
-0.0380047224462032, 0.0894022956490517, -0.0280688628554344, 
0.0527884140610695, 0.174676224589348, 0.0250600017607212, -0.103528082370758, 
-0.0280688628554344, -0.0359503589570522, -0.0529874339699745, 
-0.073478490114212, -0.0263632386922836, 0.0527884140610695), 
    V7 = c(-0.0834691673517227, 0.0285118855535984, 0.0181918852031231, 
    0.0450421050190926, 0.0335643924772739, 0.0101256892085075, 
    -0.0478062480688095, -0.0741845071315765, 0.0101256892085075, 
    -0.148965746164322, -0.0173042453825474, 0.0335643924772739, 
    0.0111529966816306, 0.0335643924772739, -0.241482585668564, 
    0.0323374196887016, 0.0374831557273865, 0.00208079349249601, 
    0.0306694488972425, -0.0391291491687298, 0.0101256892085075, 
    0.0101256892085075, 0.0450421050190926, 0.0188414938747883, 
    0.00208079349249601, 0.0101256892085075, -0.0643396899104118, 
    0.0936737284064293, 0.0335643924772739, 0.0101256892085075, 
    -0.0643396899104118, 0.0323374196887016, 0.0168080646544695, 
    0.0101256892085075, 0.110289998352528, -0.0643396899104118, 
    0.0285118855535984, 0.00208079349249601, 0.0450421050190926, 
    -0.0593610778450966, 0.016591826453805, 0.110289998352528, 
    0.0382283963263035, -0.241482585668564, -0.0384819433093071, 
    0.0229429267346859, 0.0101256892085075, -0.193015351891518, 
    -0.0816542878746986, 0.0229429267346859), V8 = c(0.188536351546645, 
    -0.14695412479341, -0.0702244397252798, 0.015599824488163, 
    0.162356040906161, 0.0322057278826833, -0.0832092929631472, 
    -0.162452442571521, 0.0479177413508296, 0.0682498225942254, 
    0.153729286044836, -0.243203143589199, 0.149779425002635, 
    -0.242116670124233, 0.109018758870661, -0.142883030232042, 
    -0.245007876306772, -0.0900559583678842, -0.247359684668481, 
    0.148495792876929, -0.0406780429184437, 0.00872406736016273, 
    0.138334958814085, -0.0638183308765292, -0.00990268588066101, 
    -0.0324675692245364, -0.114242037758231, -0.0935285966843367, 
    0.0216120602563024, 0.0322057278826833, 0.0343138063326478, 
    -0.0388489956967533, 0.0989119447767735, -0.0688016824424267, 
    0.166093233972788, -0.0274974387139082, 0.0373926516622305, 
    -0.00990268588066101, 0.140418875962496, -0.115373022854328, 
    -0.0672494322061539, 0.0669955778867006, 0.0579314436763525, 
    -0.194228617474437, -0.13398567494005, 0.117101473733783, 
    0.0771859539672732, 0.150191807188094, -0.1857496839948, 
    0.0725541273131967), GRP = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ID = c(166L, 
    61L, 54L, 240L, 179L, 272L, 76L, 87L, 224L, 164L, 13L, 125L, 
    14L, 41L, 147L, 64L, 33L, 260L, 95L, 10L, 219L, 234L, 243L, 
    53L, 261L, 279L, 123L, 177L, 127L, 269L, 142L, 63L, 18L, 
    214L, 168L, 141L, 20L, 263L, 191L, 75L, 3L, 182L, 31L, 171L, 
    74L, 170L, 249L, 154L, 67L, 4L), OUTCOME = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

EDIT:

(Excuse my poor MS Paint skills) - I was hoping for something like the following - where there are `geom_points` coloured at the begining (corresponding to 0) and then `geom_points` at the end (corresponding to 1). One point for each `geom_col`. (The `geom_points` do not need to lie on the same line as in the MS Paint version - I am happy also if they sit on top of each `geom_col`).

[image]

Comment: You may need `+facet_wrap(~ OUTCOME)`

Comment: I think it is a pretty cool idea to use `facet_wrap` based on the `OUTCOME` variable to get two distinct plots - so if I cannot find a solution to the one I proposed I will most likely go with this. However, I am plotting them in order of `OUTCOME` so adding a `facet_wrap` will surely distinguish between the two outcomes,but I think it might be cool to have a point based on the `OUTCOME` variable on the same plot.

Comment: I added an edit to the original post with something of what I was hoping for - where say `white` corresponds to `0` and `red/green` corresponds to `1` .

Comment: You could use `position = 'dodge'` `df %>% mutate(ID = factor(ID)) %>% filter(ID %in% 0:5) %>% arrange(ID, OUTCOME) %>% pivot_longer(cols = V1:V8) %>%ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = name)) + 
   geom_col(width = 1, alpha = 0.9, position = 'dodge')`

Comment: It might help if you could explain the biological phenomenon you are trying to visualize.

Comment: I have certain characteristics for 280 people.  Which is why on the x-axis of the plot you see gaps in the data - I had to use a random sample of 50 for the `dput()`). The `OUTCOME` variable is mortality. I am using Shapley values which correspond to the `value` y-axis in order to measure the contribution to the prediction of mortality. Since each person is different, different characteristics correspond to mortality, however there are certain characteristics which are consistent across patients.

Comment: Thus I am trying to show (using the `geom_point`) above each `geom_col` which patients died vs which survived based on the Shapley contribution of each patients variable. So lets say the `white` dots in the plot correspond to people who survived and the `red` dots correspond to people who died. We can see that there are negative Shapley values for the observations on the left side but there are positive Shapley values for patients on the right side. I want to further highlight this by showing which patient survied vs died by adding a colour - point above each `geom_col`.

Comment: I think your explanation really helped. See if my edited answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the biological problem really helped. How about ordering the individuals by value first and then plotting the outcome as the point?

```
df %>% 
  arrange(OUTCOME) %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(V1:V8)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(factor(ID,unique(ID)),value, sum), y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = 3, color = as.factor(OUTCOME))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","black"), labels = c("Dead","Alive")) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = name),width = 1, alpha = 0.9) + labs(x = "ID", color = "Outcome") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Better than I had pictured! Thanks!